# How to fix "import tensorflow as tf " error in windows while using jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hi all im trying to import tensorflow but unable to perform the operation. whereas on the other hand is able to install it in jupyter notebook. Please help !

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Above is the code I have tried and the error I have got

Comment: What versions are you using? try running `!pip show numpy` and `!pip show tensorflow` within jupyter

Comment: HI @ChrisA im using 

Name: numpy
Version: 1.15.4 and Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.13.1  . Do you have nay futher suggestion? if so please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Anaconda3. If you have install the tensorflow by pip, remove it, then run

```
!conda install numpy tensorflow
```

If you have GPU, use tensorflow-gpu instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your numpy installation is somehow corrupt or completely broken. Please reinstall numpy.

Answer (score 0):

It's a `numpy` problem. Run:

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy
```